# What would I need to write if I wanted to make a timer cancel based on the increasing of the score? (Corona)

Tags: object, if-statement, timer, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to cancel a timer when the player chooses the correct character. I have come to the conclusion that the two possible ways to do this are to cancel the timer based on the increase of the score, or on the initialization of the addEventListener. I have tried to fiddle around with some possible options, but none of them worked. Any ideas on what to write to make the condition viable so that the timer will cancel based on such event happening? here is the code I have thus far:

```
function timeClock(event)
if event.time > 2000 then
storyboard.gotoScene( "restartEasy" )
randomImage.alpha = 0
else
timer.cancel( event.source ) 
end
end

function endGame(event)
if imageFile == "redbox.png" then
timer.performWithDelay( 2000, timeClock )
randomImage.alpha = 0
mydata.score = mydata.score + 1
scoreText.text = mydata.score
button1.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button1.y = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.y = math.random( 55, 300)
imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, centerX, screenTop + 20)
storyboard.gotoScene( "restartEasy" )
randomImage.alpha = 0

end
end

function endGame2(event)
if imageFile == "bluebox.png" then
timer.performWithDelay( 2000, timeClock )
randomImage.alpha = 0
mydata.score = mydata.score + 1
scoreText.text = mydata.score
button1.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button1.y = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.y = math.random( 55, 300)
imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, centerX, screenTop + 20)
else
storyboard.gotoScene( "restartEasy" )
randomImage.alpha = 0

end
end

button1:addEventListener("touch", endGame)
button2:addEventListener("touch", endGame2)

end
```

Comment: If anyone needs to know any more information to help, just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Name the timer a public variable for instance

```
timer1 = timer.performWithDelay(2000, timeClock)
```

Then in your function cancel the timer using

```
timer.cancel(timer1)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. However, the timer itself isn't the problem, because the way you suggested it didn't change anything. Because of this, the condition has to be the problem. Just in case you forgot what I wanted to accomplish, I wanted the timer to end based on the changing of the score, but the problem is that I don't know how I would write that as a condition. Any Ideas?